# Nesting Case statements for different Fields SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a case statement that checks several criteria to enter data into a specific field named `Column_1`.

Being that you can't amend two fields within the same case statement, I feel the best choice is to nest another case statement to amend the second field.

My code is as follows.

```
UPDATE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL        
                SET Column_1 = CASE        
                     WHEN Column_1 != NULL AND Time_Data_1 IS NOT NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Day'        
                     WHEN Time_Data_1 IS NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NULL THEN 'Hol'                                            
                ELSE 
                   SET Column_2 = CASE 
                     WHEN Time_Data_3 IS NULL THEN 'Something'
                   ELSE NULL
                   END         
                END               
             WHERE Staff_No = 1903 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/2/1' AND '2016/3/1'
```

So in the above code, when the criteria for `column_1` throws the `ELSE` , I want a different column `Column_2` to be tested for new conditions.

How do you write in the second case statement?

Comment: `!= NULL` won't work with ansi nulls enabled.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, what should I be using instead? Thanks for pointing this out to me.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, never mind I see my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
UPDATE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
  SET Column_1 = CASE
     WHEN Column_1 IS NOT NULL AND Time_Data_1 IS NOT NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Day'
     WHEN Time_Data_1 IS NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NULL THEN 'Hol'
   ELSE Column_1
   END,
   Column_2 = CASE
     WHEN NOT (Column_1 IS NOT NULL AND Time_Data_1 IS NOT NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NOT NULL
               AND
               Time_Data_1 IS NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NULL)
          AND
          Time_Data_3 IS NULL
     THEN 'Something'
     END
```

The overall idea is:

1. actually finish the update to **Column_1**,
2. move on to **Column_2**:

   - repeat the test for **Column_1** (or rather their respective and combined opposite) *(This part might need some twisting to get the logic right.)*, and
   - add the additional test for **Column_2**.

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: This best servers what I want to do. Thanks for the effort to help me. UV.

Comment: @KyloRen: Just keep an eye on your **Column_1** conditions when repeating them for **Column_2**, though. As soon as some `OR` is added, you can't any longer just `AND` the respective tests.

Comment: What do I do when adding another `WHEN` criteria to the column_2 case?

Comment: If I understand your intention correctly (along the lines `Time_Data_3 IS NULL` was not matched: Just add the `WHEN` in before **Column_2**'s `END`. Otherwise: Please provide an example.

Comment: Below this, `THEN 'Something'`

Comment: Yes, exactly there.

Comment: What is the reason for putting in the `WHEN NOT`, could you not just leave those lines out?

Comment: @KyloRen: This does depend solely on your requirements (and your data): In your problem description, you want to check two sets of conditions before setting **Column_1**. `ELSE` only a third condition is to be considered in order to apply "Something" to **Column_2**. If either (i) you want exclusively the latter condition enforced, or (ii) the previous processing is (always) such, that when the `UPDATE` at hand is being executed, "Time_Data_3 IS NULL" does only hold, if the **Column_1** related conditions do not - ony then, you should not / do not need to replicate these conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your case, try this:

```
           UPDATE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL        
            SET Column_1 = CASE        
                 WHEN Column_1 is not NULL AND Time_Data_1 IS NOT NULL AND  Time_Data_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Day'        
                 WHEN Time_Data_1 IS NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NULL THEN 'Hol' 
                 else Column_1  end,                                           
                Column_2= CASE 
                 WHEN Column_1 is not NULL AND Time_Data_1 IS NOT NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NOT NULL THEN Column_2       
                 WHEN Time_Data_1 IS NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NULL THEN Column_2
                 WHEN Time_Data_3 IS NULL THEN 'Something'
                 ELSE NULL
               END         

         WHERE Staff_No = 1903 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/2/1' AND '2016/3/1'
```

Comment: UV for the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
UPDATE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL        
        SET Column_1 = (CASE        
             WHEN Column_1 is not NULL AND Time_Data_1 IS NOT NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Day'        
             WHEN Time_Data_1 IS NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NULL THEN 'Hol'                                            
             ELSE Column_1 end)
           ,Column_2 = case when (CASE        
             WHEN Column_1 is not NULL AND Time_Data_1 IS NOT NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Day'        
             WHEN Time_Data_1 IS NULL AND Time_Data_2 IS NULL THEN 'Hol' else 'Error' end)='Error' and 
             Time_Data_3 IS NULL THEN 'Something' ELSE Column_2 --(Here you have to handle else condition as per requirement)
           END                    
     WHERE Staff_No = 1903 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/2/1' AND '2016/3/1'
```

Comment: Why did you put a `else 'error'` in the nested statement? What is I don't want the data changed? As you have it, the columns data will be either `Hol` or `error`

Comment: If it is error then update data of same column only thats why i have use error keyword

Comment: Could update the statement so that when it is an error it does nothing to the data?

Comment: it will update the same data to that column. try for some sample data then you will get idea.

Comment: UV for the help. Thanks